# Water From Morning Netilat Yadayim

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, ruach-rah

If the water from morning netilat yadayim dried on a particular area, and was then touched by an individual who washed their hands, would one then have to wash their hands again?

Comment: I always thought water evaporates, in which case it’s no longer there and your touching the hand, not “dried” water.

Comment: Say one didn’t it it a sink, but then the water dried on an area on the sink, so on so forth.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.4.2?lang=bi